# How to reverse pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I need to reverse my pyspark dataframe. Is there a way to do it in pyspark in a efficient way??
My datetime column is reverse so I need to reverse my dataframe

```
+-------------------+-------+
|               date|value_1|
+-------------------+-------+
|2018-11-30 23:59:24|  28.02|
|2018-11-30 23:58:54|  28.02|
|2018-11-30 23:58:24|  28.03|
+-------------------+-------+
```

Is there a way reverse the dataframe in pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your dataframe is sorted using `date` column in a descending manner. We can order it by [`orderBy()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.orderBy) or [`sort()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sort) which essentially provide the same functionality :

```
df = df.orderBy("date", ascending=True)
# OR
df = df.sort("date", ascending=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought of the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps more general solution could be constructed by setting up an index, reversing the order the index and finally dropping the index. This would work on any dataframe. Example code:

```
# revert the order of a dataframe
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
# create spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('some name').getOrCreate()
# create a frame
df = spark.createDataFrame([('a',12), ('c',10), ('b',9)], ['col1', 'col2'])
df.show()
# reverse the order of the rows
inv_df = df.withColumn('index', f.monotonically_increasing_id()).orderBy(f.col('index').desc()).drop('index')
```